# Query regarding ExtJs 4 slow loading

Tags: java, javascript, json, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm using ExtJs 4 ,Java & hibernate to develope a web application.
Controller is Struts 1
Front end is completely in Extjs4.
I'm facing the issue: slow loading of first page.Sometimes it takes 1 or 2 minutes.
Till Now i included complete Extjs4 files that having size 49 MB in my application.

Comment: why are your extjs files that big? ext-all-dev.js has 6.2MB where do you get that?

Comment: @Jandalf i downloaded it from http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/download

Comment: thats right, but if you load your page in the browser, how much MB are transferred?

Comment: My biggest application (cca 800 javascript files + Ext) compiles into 2.9 MB. There must be something else wrong.

Comment: @Jan S Now I included ext-all-dev.js it's now pretty faster but some css issues are there  can you pls tell me which all packages i need to include along with this  .

Comment: @Pankajkumarsharma I give you an answer to explain these files

Comment: @Jan S , Now I got.
It's Working Properly (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need 3 files for a working ExtJS system:

Development:

- `ext-all-dev.js`
- one language file from the `locale` folder (e.g. `ext-lang-en_GB.js`)
- one theme file from the `resources/css` folder (e.g. `ext-all-neptune-debug.css`)

Productive:

- `ext-all.js`
- one language file from the `locale` folder (e.g. `ext-lang-en_GB.js`)
- one theme file from the `resources/css` folder (e.g. `ext-all-neptune.css`)

the development files are not minified so you see where an exception occurs.

Comment: Now I got. It's Working Properly (y)

Comment: @Pankajkumarsharma if an answer was helpful mark it as accepted and click on the hook under the down vote button